Visual Studio 2022 does NOT show Build log on Output window. It also does not show me error messages
I recently got a new computer and installed Visual Studio 2022 community.
In the previous version, when I build a project, it showed me which subroutine is being compiled and if there were errors, it showed the error messages; however, in the newer version, it does not say anything but 3 lines of build messages (as shown below):

Also, if I intentionally write a function wrong, it does not say anything:

Anyone knows how to fix this? Please help me. Much appreciated.

First place to check is Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Output Window. There might be more settings specific to your programming language which should also be found under Tools -> Options

I checked this with my previous computer. All settings under Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Output Window are same; however, the newer does not show me the build log nor error messages.

Is the code you are building the same as the code you are editing?  Is the Startup project the one you wish to build?  Are you picking the file to be edited from the project/solution or ctrl-O to open the directory and pick a file?  The latter method may not pick the file that is in the project and as such will not force recompilation of the project file.

Hi cup, I am working on my own work. Sorry I probably didn't understand what you mentioned above; however, when I build, a build log.htm is generated under the configuration folder. I used to be able to see the build log on Output window in VS. But now I have to manually open the log to see the output.

Does this help at all? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72721783/fortran-in-visual-studio-2022
